# Unstable Oracle Database connection for Java-project

Tags: java, oracle11g, nullpointerexception, glassfish-5

I'm a student and one of our assignments is creating a Java web project on a local GlassFish 5 webserver. The database used for this project is an OracleDB running locally in a Docker container.

I almost finished my project but some pages keep crashing (NullPointerException). I have to retrieve database records and save them in an ArrayList. But sometimes the SQLConnection doesn't return anything (but the records DO exist) and my code tries to preform actions on that empty ArrayList.

Now, as I said, the connection appears to be unstable, because at some seemingly random moments the database does respond with the appropriate records.

It's really frustrating and I cannot continue working on this project without a stable database connection. So I'd appreciate hearing from people with some more experience :-)

Thank you for your time.

Code for running a query:

```
protected ResultSet getRecords(String query) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            return (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

Code with the query:

```
List<Uitlening> uitleningen = new ArrayList<Uitlening>();

        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = getRecords("SELECT * FROM uitlening");

            while(resultSet.next()) { //Here the code crashes because the ResultSet can sometimes be empty.
```

I think this is the actual error message: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

But I don't really understand what I should do now..

```
 try {
        ResultSet resultSet = getRecords("SELECT * FROM uitlening");

        while(resultSet.next()) { 
            Uitlening uitlening = new Uitlening();
            uitlening.setNr(resultSet.getInt("nr"));                
            uitleningen.add(uitlening);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.addSuppressed(e);
    } 
    return uitleningen;
```

---

It might be nothing, but it almost looks like the error only occurs when I run 2 queries almost immediately after each other. Is it possible that closing the connection takes a while?

Comment: I added the code @Andreas

Comment: Is the Stacktrace telling you which line of code is causing nullpointer? Please tell us, so far the code you posted looks ok.

Comment: As detailMessage I found: `Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found` @Enzokie

Comment: and the line is `while(resultSet.next()) {` I think  because I returned `null` after the exception

Comment: Can you post the next other code after that line? because `next()` is not supposed to throw NullPointer regardless if your DB is empty since it returns boolean.

Comment: *"I think because I returned null after the exception"* Correct. Don't catch and ignore exceptions. Unless you have very good reasons to do so, don't catch exceptions at all.

Comment: If the ORA-12519 error is intermittent, it is likely because of limited number of connections on the server, and all the connections are in use, e.g. because too many students are using it at the same time, or only a few students are using it but their code it bad and they forget to close the connections, causing resource leaks (euphemistically called "memory leak").

Comment: @Andreas, Thank you. I added the code you requested to the question. But still, why does i't return an exception, the query sometimes works.

Comment: @Andreas, when are connections closed? Is it possible to close a connection after  I've got the data?

Comment: @Lenny The connection is closed when you call [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that you run into the database connection problem because your code does not properly close the database connections as well as the statements and result sets.

A statement will also close its active result set. Most JDBC will also close the statement if the connection is closed.

So closing the connection is the most important part. It cannot be achieved with your current code structure because you create it in an inner method and do not return it.

It has also been mentioned that the exception handling is poor because you ignore exceptions and return *null* instead causing seemingly unrelated crashes later. In many cases it might be easier to declare that the method throws `SQLException`.

You might want to change your code like so:

```
List<Uitlening> retrieveData() {
    final String query = "SELECT * FROM uitlening";
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)) {
        return processResultSet(resultSet);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

List<Uitlening> processResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    List<Uitlening> uitleningen = new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Uitlening uitlening = new Uitlening();
        uitlening.setNr(resultSet.getInt("nr"));
        uitleningen.add(uitlening);
    }
    return uitleningen;
}
```

It closes the connection, the statement and the result set by using try/catch blocks that take advantage of `AutoClosable`s (in this case: `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`).

The method `processResultSet` declares the `SQLException` so it doesn't need to handle it.

The code is rearrange so the data is fully processed before the code leaves the try/catch block that closes the connection.

Comment: Thank you @Codo for your answer, I changed my code. But I still sometimes get the ORA-12519 error. It might be nothing, but it almost looks like the error only occurs when I run 2 queries almost immediately after each other. Is it possible that closing the connection takes a while? I'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: Your answer really helped me al lot! Closing the appropriate connections was 1 part of the problem, I also had to allow more processes in the database settings, because Java closed the connections faster than the database could handle. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: As opening a new connection is expensive and as they aren't immediately closed as you have experienced, you might want to look into connection pools. They reuse connections and therefore are faster and more efficient.